# How to get value from a template rendered several times with Meteor?

Tags: jquery, templates, meteor

I want to get different durations of audios inside a helper, from a template that is rendered several times. Is there any way to do that other than inserting the audio duration in the database? I've tried a lot of stuff, some not recommended at all, and none of it works. The ones that show me anything, show me only the duration of the first audio. Here is one of the uglier jerryrigs that actually return a number, but it's still pretty broken and causes a setInterval that doesn't stop.

```
Meteor.myaudioplayer.helpers({
   audioduration: function(){
     //if using ReactiveVar...
    audio = $("audio").get(0);
    instance = Template.instance();

        if (!instance.audioduration.get() || isNaN(parseInt(audio.duration))) {
              audioLenght = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
                    var totaltime = parseInt(audio.duration, 10);
                    var mins = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60, 10);
                    var secs = totaltime - mins * 60;
                    var gimmethetime = mins + ':' + (secs > 9 ? secs : '0' + secs);

                    instance.audioduration.set(gimmethetime);
                    return gimmethetime;

              }, 500);
        } 

        else {
            Meteor.clearInterval(audioLenght);
            return instance.audioduration.get();
        }
      }
});
```

This is my HTML if it somehow helps.

```html
<div class="myplayer {{label}}>
    
    <div class=" gutter ">
   <div class="loading">  
   </div>
   <div class="played"> 
   </div> 
   <div class="handle"> 
   </div>
   </div>

 <div class="controls ">
   <span class="playtoggle glyphicon glyphicon-play "></span>
  <div class="volume-control ">
    <span class="volume glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up "></span>

   <div class="volume-gutter hidden ">
     <div class="volume-meter ">
     <div class="volume-handle "></div>
     </div>
   </div>

        </div>
   
    <span class="title">{{audioName}}</span>
    <span class="timeleft pull-right"> {{audioplayed}} / {{audioduration}}</span>
    </div>
 </div>

<audio class={{label}}>
  <source src={{mysource}} format={{myformat}}/>
</audio>
```

It's also important to get the current audio position and and audio duration in other parts of the player, but as those are inside events triggered by the user, they are less problematic, since I can ask the browser what the elements look like using the event target as a parameter.

EDIT
Someone asked for my code on the "play" button. Here it is. I'm still on the way to adjusting the variables so I can have two play functions at the same time, but works just fine. 
NOTE: I changed the HTML  above to match this code, since I messed with some class names between versions.

```js
"click .playtoggle": function(event) {
  thisplayer = $(event.target).parents(".audioplayer").attr("id");
  thisaudio = $("#" + thisplayer).find("audio").get(0);

  console.log(thisaudio.duration);

  //Playing
  if (!playing) {
    playing = true;
    $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").removeClass("glyphicon-play");
    $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").addClass("glyphicon-pause");
    thisaudio.play();

    playIt = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
      //vars for the visual aspect
      var handlepadding = parseInt($("#" + thisplayer).find(".handle").css("width")) / 2;
      var gutterwidth = $("#" + thisplayer).find(".gutter").width() - handlepadding;
      var soundcoordinates = parseInt(thisaudio.currentTime, 10);
      var totaltime = parseInt(thisaudio.duration, 10);
      var playedgutter = gutterwidth * soundcoordinates / totaltime;

      // If user is not messing with the handle, give the position
      if (!draghandle) {
        $("#" + thisplayer).find(".played").css("width", playedgutter + "px");
        $("#" + thisplayer).find(".handle").css("left", playedgutter + "px");
      }

      // If the audio has come to an end, acknowledge that it has ended
      if (soundcoordinates == totaltime) {
        playing = false;
        $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").removeClass("glyphicon-pause");
        $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").addClass("glyphicon-play");
        Meteor.clearInterval(playIt);

      }

      // Send the data to the timer
      instance.timeplayed.set(soundcoordinates);

    }, 500);

    return;
  }
  // END Playing

  // Pausing
  if (playing) {
    playing = false;
    $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").removeClass("glyphicon-pause");
    $("#" + thisplayer).find(".playtoggle").addClass("glyphicon-play");
    Meteor.clearInterval(playIt);
    thisaudio.pause();
    return;
  }
//END pausing

}
```

Comment: can you post the event when someone hits play? can you use jquery there to change the duration? have you tried using reactive variables or Tracker.dependency?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm still in the process of translating everything from what I had (a player supposed to be the only one in the page) to what I want (several players rendered from a single template) and everything started glitching due to it being half done. Had to debug the code first so I could post something that works and I'll be doing so below.

Comment: To answer your other questions, I never used jquery to change duration of an audio, but I can get the correct audio duration from there. I don't know how to use Tracker.dependency or reactive variables on helpers other than the way I've done above.

Comment: Stack overflow recommended I edited my original post, so it's edited.

Comment: if you put the `console.log(thisaudio.duration);` inside the playIt setInterval, does it print the the result you need? If so you can use jquery to set the text of the span duration element, or change the value of a reactive helper that returns a value through a helper

Comment: That would work nicely for the span that indicates the current time, since the user has to click on something for it to change (the play button or the handle), but I'd like something to already be on the players as the page loads. As the calls on the onRendered return either the whole window or the first instance, I haven't found a way to make this work from there yet.

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do with the onRendered? I would assume you can start with `<span id="duration">00:00</span>`, else post the code for the onRendered

Comment: I don't have the code for the onRendered yet. When I had this template rendered only once at a time, a helper did the job, but with more than one instance the helper is no use and that is the point of the question. I want audioduration to show how long the audio lasts, that's all. As far as I have gotten trying to find a solution, I got an array out of the available player ids with

`$(".audioplayer").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();`

and am trying to make that give me the corresponding audio duration values with a for loop so I can insert them into their corresponding timers.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<span class="timeleft pull-right"> {{audioplayed}} / <span id="duration"></span></span>
```

js func

```
function  gimmethetime(audio){
  var totaltime = parseInt(audio.duration, 10);
  var mins = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60, 10);
  var secs = totaltime - mins * 60;
  var timeLeft = mins + ':' + (secs > 9 ? secs : '0' + secs);
  $("#duration").text(timeLeft);
}
```

Using jQuery to set the time at the start

```
Template.myaudioplayer.onRendered(
   function(){
        audio = $("audio").get(0);
        if (audio) {
             gimmethetime(audio);
        } 
      }
);
```

when user hits play

```
 ...
 playIt = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    gimmethetime(thisaudio);
    ....
 }
 ...
```

Comment: This is a good partial answer, but I can't mark it as the solution because it  has a few problems:  `$("audio").get(0)` returns only the first `<audio>` tags in the body; the audio variable returns "NaN" because the template hasn't finished rendering yet as the first function is run; the code is inside onRendered(), so it never gets run again and the template gets stuck with NaN.

Comment: In the end, thank you for your time and for the back and forth. I may not have come up with the prettiest answer, but my code does what I needed it to do now, and that's way more than I had when I asked.

Comment: you are welcome. ya reactivity in meteor is still something I am trying to master.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to my particular problem. It's probably not the prettiest thing, and it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, since it doesn't use helpers anymore, but it works. I had to change the HTML a bit, so now, instead of two helpers inside the timer ".timeleft" span (one for progress and another for duration), I have two sets of spans.

```html
<span class="timeleft pull-right">
 <span class="audioplayed"></span> /<span class="audioduration"></span>
</span>
```

Inside the onRendered, I have:

```js
      audio = $("audio").get(0);

      idArray = $(".audioplayer").map(function() {
        return this.id;
      }).get();

      if (audio.duration && !isNaN(audio.duration)) {
        Meteor.clearInterval(getDuration);
      } else {
        getDuration = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
          for (i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
            var audioduration = $("#" + idArray[i]).find("audio").get(0).duration;
            var totaltime = parseInt(audioduration, 10);
            var mins = Math.floor(audioduration / 60, 10);
            var secs = totaltime - mins * 60;
            var gimmethetime = mins + ':' + (secs > 9 ? secs : '0' + secs);

            $("#" + idArray[i]).find(".audioduration").text(gimmethetime);
          }
          if (audio.duration && !isNaN(audio.duration)) {
            Meteor.clearInterval(getDuration);
          }
        }, 500);
      }
```

Let me explain what I did. 
Inside the *onRendered* the variable *audio* returns only the first audio file and it comes back as NaN because the element has not quite finished rendering yet. In order to get the two values, I created an array with the ids from each div.audioplayer that has been rendered (the idArray variable looked liked this: [label1, label2]). I then ran those ids in a for loop to get the audio durations and write then on the right element (the child of the div#label[i]).

However, this runs into the same problem of the audio variable: the template hasn't finished rendering, so when I ask my document how long are those audios, it doesn't know. My workaround was to put my loop in a setInterval, so that it keeps asking until it gets an answer, and then it stops. I can use the audio variable for validation, since when it gets back a value it is likely the other audios will too. Now, I have the two audio durations, each in it's corresponding timer for this template that was rendered twice.

[image: Template of the audioplayer rendered twice]

I intend to use the same technique to update the audio progress in the audioplayed portion of the timer.